# How to send the value of a variable between two views in yii

Tags: php, yii

Suppose, in Yii framework if any other parameter has to be sent to any other file. How can I do this.
If from admin.php I have to send another variable to update.php. How can I do this

Comment: Please you put your code.

Comment: @msoa array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
                        'template'=>'{update}',
                        'buttons' => array(
                    'view' => array (                   
                        'url' => 'Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("/apartmentSettings/update", array("Id"=>$data->Id,"approval"=>$approval))',
                    ),

Comment: Clear your requirement what you want to achieve ??

Answer (score 0):

If `update.php` is child view inside `admin.php`, you can do follow on `admin.php`

```
$this->renderPartial('update', array('param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2', ...))
```

(noted this example `update.php` is same folder level with `admin.php`)

If both of files came from two different actions, or they have their own URL look like below

```
public function actionAdmin(){ ...; $this->render('admin');}
public function actionUpdate(){ ...; $this->render('update');}
```

you have to treat it as query string

```
admin.php
```

Example:

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Go to Update',array(
'controller/update', 'param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2', ...)); ?>
```

More about Yii URL Managger and querystring

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url